# Suggestions to relate 3 SQL entities

Tags: mysql, sql, model, entity

I have 3 different entities in my relational database. The entity called 'Competencia' has many to many relation with two more entities 'Nivel', 'Funcion' or neither of them. 'CompetenciaTipo' is the field in 'Competencia' that tells me if 'Competencia' is related to 'Nivel, 'Funcion' or none of them. I have and intermediate table in both cases to work with those many-to-many-relations, you can look part of my ER diagram in the following image.

[image: ER diagram]

I will need to build a SQL query to bring all rows in 'Competencia' table and the relations with the other tables (if any) but it seems that it will be a complex query.

Do you think my model design is appropriate? Do you have any other suggestions to get the same result?

Thanks

Comment: Based simply on the table structure and explanation provided the table structure is fine and is the appropriate for most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Select Competencia Funcions:-

```
SELECT c.*, f.*    -- 
FROM Competencia c
LEFT JOIN CompetenciaFuncion cf ON cf.CompetenciaId = c.CompetenciaId 
LEFT JOIN Funcion f ON f.FuncionId = cf.FuncionId
WHERE {......insert additional conditions..... }
```

Select Competencia Nivels:-

```
SELECT c.*, n.*    -- 
FROM Competencia c
LEFT JOIN CompetenciaNivel cn ON cn.CompetenciaId = c.CompetenciaId 
LEFT JOIN Nivel n ON n.NivelId = cn.NivelId
WHERE {......insert additional conditions..... }
```

LEFT JOINs ensure that all of the details from the competencia table are returned and anything from the Funcion/Nivel table.  NOTE: that most times you want to display the results in a grid (or similar), then the `c.*` part in the SELECT would be replaced by simply  c.CompetenciaId, so that you have the key, but don't repeat the data from the competencia table unnecessarily.

These queries can also form the basis of VIEWs, if they are used over and over again.

Comment: What will happen in case I want to relate 'Competencia' with 'Funcion' and 'Nivel' both at the same time? With the example provided I would need to merge both queries results with an additional job, I think.

Comment: Yes that is right. Normally though you wouldn't retrieve all the details from all 3 tables at once (in a single row), because data will get duplicated across multiple rows.  It is better to think of it as a parent-child relationship.  Noramlly you retrieve the parents you want and then retrieve the related children to those parents, in separate result sets.